# how change old javascript function into modern javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am a little bit old school javascript coder I have this code which changes the word with thias sign [yellow] for example:

**same**  ======> **s[yellow]m**

**name**  ======> **n[yellow]m**

my question is how to change this code into modern javascript using ternary, map functions.

```
function yellowMaker(word) {
  var newWord = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    if (word[i] === "a" && word[i+2] === "e") {
      newWord += "[yellow]";
    } else if (word[i-2] === "a" && word[i] === "e") {
      newWord += "";
    } else {
      newWord += word[i];
    }
  }
  return newWord;
}
```

Comment: `const yellowMaker = word => word.replace(/a(.)e/g, "[yellow]$1");` -- doesn't need to be excessively "modern", just use a basic regex instead of manually parsing the string.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol This should be an answer (I'd upvote it)!

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following using ternary and map function,

```js
const yellowMaker = (word) => {
  return Array.from(word).map((char, index, arr) => {
    const newChar = char === 'a' && arr[index+2] === 'e' ? '[yellow]' : char;
    arr[index+2] = newChar !== char ? '' : arr[index+2];
    return newChar;
  }).join('');
}

console.log(yellowMaker('same'));
console.log(yellowMaker('name'));
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple search and replace with a regex would also do the job here.

```js
function yellowMaker(word) {
  return word.replace(/a(.)e/gs, "[yellow]$1");
}

console.log(yellowMaker("same"));
console.log(yellowMaker("name"));
console.log(yellowMaker("aaee"));
console.log(yellowMaker("abcadefg"));
```

The only scenario this does not cover is `"aaee"` which should result in `"[yellow]a[yellow]e"`. However the above solution produces `"[yellow]ae"` If you do want to cover this scenario you can still use a regular expression, but your current solution might be cleaner.

```js
function yellowMaker(word) {
  const regex = /a(.)e/gs;
  let match, index = 0, result = "";
  while (match = regex.exec(word)) {
    result += word.slice(index, match.index) + "[yellow]" + match[1];
    index = regex.lastIndex;
    regex.lastIndex -= 2;
  }
  return result + word.slice(index, word.length);
}

console.log(yellowMaker("same"));
console.log(yellowMaker("name"));
console.log(yellowMaker("aaee"));
console.log(yellowMaker("abcadefg"));
```

The regex `s` flag is relatively new in JavaScript. If you need something that is more compatible, replace the `.` with `[^]` (see: [Regular expression syntax cheatsheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet)) but a lot of people also use `[\s\S]`. After replacing the `.` you can drop the `s` flag.

`.` without the `s` flag does not match newline characters. Whereas your current code does match the string `"a\ne"`. If you don't care about newline characters you can leave the `.` and omit the `s` flag.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.fname = "Rahul";
  }
}
class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.lname = "mankar";
  }
}

class C extends B {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.name = this.fname + " " + this.lname;
  }
  getFullName() {
    return this.name;
  }
}
const obj = new C();
console.log(obj.getFullName());

https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-architecture-thlryz?file=/index.js:0-345
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).